# Changing hash throw: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to change the hash in the URL when I trigger an action (a click for instance) using a pattern like `#/param-1=foo&param-2=bar`

In a fresh Drupal 8 theme, when I try this, I got an error saying
*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/test=0*

It works fine when I try with `#param1-foo_param2-bar` but I would like more flexibility. It looks like jquery is trying to consider the hash as a selector and returns an error that says it's not a valid selector.

Here is the code I use on a fresh classy based theme:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            $('.layout-container', context).once('myModuleBehavior').each(function () {
                $('.site-name a').on('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    console.log("clicking on logo");
                    window.location.hash = "/test=0";
                });
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

And here is the result I get from chrome console:

[image: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression]

Comment: Nope, this is pretty much on topic cuz it comes from Drupal core. And handleFragmentLinkClickOrHashChange (form.js?v=8.5.11:137) i still an issue if you are doing a JS app that relies on hashchange for nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleFragmentLinkClickOrHashChange` is a function defined in the Drupal script `form.js` which attempts to scroll to the corresponding element when the hash (anchor tag) changes, mimicking browser behavior when the anchor tag is changed through visiting a link.

I know it's common to (ab)use the anchor tag like this in Angular and other frameworks but looks like you are going to struggle if you try to combine it with a regular Drupal frontend.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Alfred Armstrong pointing down `form.js`. It seems this event is responsible of that behaviour:

```
 $(window).on('hashchange.form-fragment', debouncedHandleFragmentLinkClickOrHashChange);
```

It looks like unbinding it in my custom .js does the trick. We won't benefit from the scroll functionality `form.js` provides, but we could recreate it with:

```
$(window).off('hashchange.form-fragment').on('hashchange', function() {
    //something that scroll 
});
```